# Reference request: "continuity at a point"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, definition

Does anyone know of a standard textbook reference where continuity at a point is defined?

Specifically I am looking for some $\epsilon$-$\delta$ version of continuity or some topological definition that states roughly if a function is continuous at a point, then there exists some pre-image that contains an open set containing that point.

Comment: Continuity is (almost?) always defined at a single point first. You can find various definitions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition, e.g. “Definition in terms of neighborhoods”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance, in Stephen Willard's *General Topology*, we can find this definition:

**Definition:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$. Then $f$ is *continuous* at $x_0$ if for each neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ in $Y$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $f(U)\subset V$.